# Finding words in sentences

Tags: c++

I have a programming assignment I cannot finish. This one part is killing me.

> Accept some text from the user. Accept the string that needs to be searched. Your program is supposed to print the number of occurrences of the string found within the text, and the position at which the pattern was found. Look at the following sample output:
>
> > Sample Output:
> >     Enter text: “Call me Ishmael. Some years ago - never mind how long precisely - having little or no money in my purse, and nothing particular to interest me on shore, I thought I would sail about a little and see the watery part of the world. It is a way I have of driving off the spleen, and regulating the circulation”
> >
> > String to search – “Some years ago”
> >
> > Number of occurrences – 1
> >
> > Position Found – 18

This is my function:

```
void getText()
{
    string itext, word;
    int position;
    bool done =  false;
    cout << "Enter some text" << endl;
    cin >> itext;
    cout << "Enter the word or phrase to wish to find" << endl;
    cin >> word;
    char text[itext.length()];
    char search[word.length()];

    for(int i = 0; i < itext.length(); i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < word.length(); j++)
        {
            if(text[i] == search[j])
            {
                position = i;
                cout << position;
            }
        } 
     }
}
```

Comment: This a whale of a problem.  You want to look for a character NOT matching and go on to the next position.

Comment: text and search has nothing in it. Moreover you need to check if the itext[i] matches word[0] and then continue matching else just increment i;

Comment: When you are inside the inner word.length loop you are comparing each character of the word string with the same character of the phrase string. You are reporting success if any one character in the word matches the current phrase character.

Comment: What you want to do is substring matching and counting. You definitely want to NOT use char[] and use std::string instead. You also want to look at std::string::find maybe. For the algo this is a good reference http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm

Answer (score 2):

This might get you started: (pseudo code from the Knuth-Morris-Pratt algorithm)

```
algorithm kmp_search:
    input:
        an array of characters, S (the text to be searched)
        an array of characters, W (the word sought)
    output:
        an integer (the zero-based position in S at which W is found)

    define variables:
        an integer, m ← 0 (the beginning of the current match in S)
        an integer, i ← 0 (the position of the current character in W)
        an array of integers, T (the table, computed elsewhere)

    while m + i < length(S) do
        if W[i] = S[m + i] then
            if i = length(W) - 1 then
                return m
            let i ← i + 1
        else
            if T[i] > -1 then
                let m ← m + i - T[i], i ← T[i]
            else
                let i ← 0, m ← m + 1

    (if we reach here, we have searched all of S unsuccessfully)
    return the length of S
```

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm

EDIT:Simpler and using c++ std library :

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main ()
{

  std::string str ("There are two needles in this haystack with needles.");
  std::string str2 ("needle");

  // different member versions of find in the same order as above:
  std::size_t found = 0;
  int matches = 0;
  std::vector<size_t> positions;

  while( found = str.find(str2) != std::string::npos) {
      matches++;
      positions.push_back(found);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make your live much easier if you will use std::string in this task instead of char[]. All you have to do is to load your text into a std::string and then use its find method as described here:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/

By the way, I am not sure that these lines can work as you can create not dynamic array only with a constant expression length

```
char text[itext.length()];
char search[word.length()];
```